# Why private/protected members must originate from the same class for type compatibility?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

In [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), it says:

> Private and protected members in a class affect their compatibility.
>   When an instance of a class is checked for compatibility, if the
>   instance contains a private member, then the target type must also
>   contain a private member that originated from the same class.
>   Likewise, the same applies for an instance with a protected member.
>   This allows a class to be assignment compatible with its super class,
>   but not with classes from a different inheritance hierarchy which
>   otherwise have the same shape.

While type compatibility in TypeScript being structural (duck typing):

```
class Animal {
    feet: number;
}

class Size {
    feet: number;
}

let a: Animal = new Size; // Ok!
```

the cases for class containing protected/private members is actually nominal:

```
class Animal {
    private feet: number;
}

class Size {
    private feet: number;
}

let a: Animal = new Size; // Error!
```

Could anyone explain why this inconsistency exists in TypeScript between public and protected/private members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design to prevent private/protected members from being accessed from a different type.

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7755:

> Consider something like this
>
> ```
> class Foo {
>     private versionNumber = 10;
>
>     public compareTo(other: Foo) {
>         return this.getVersion() === other.getVersion();
>     }
>
>     private getVersion() {
>         return this.versionNumber;
>     }
> }
>
> class Bar {
>     private myName = 'default;'
>     public compareTo(other: Bar) {
>         return this.myName === other.myName;
>     }
>
>     private getVersion() {
>         /* ... DANGEROUS CODE HERE ...*/
>         return -1;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> By inspection, `Bar#getVersion` is never invoked -- it's a private
>   method and there are no calls to it from the originating class. That
>   inspection ought to be sufficient for code that doesn't actively try
>   to work around the typechecker.
>
> But this code does invoke `Bar#getVersion`:
>
> ```
> let f = new Foo();
> let b = new Bar();
> f.compareTo(b);
> ```